# Misconstrued Monomials

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

There exists an equation, assuming `n` and `x` are positive,

[image: equation]

that expresses the relationship between two monomials, one being a common misrepresentation of the other. Many people make the simple mistake of equating these (i.e. `3x^2` and `(3x)^2`).

#### Challenge

Given a positive integer, `i`, determine and return the solution `n` and `x` with the smallest sum as an array `[n, x]`. In the case of a tie, any solution set is acceptable.

#### Test Cases

```
62658722541234765
[15, 11]

202500
[4, 15]

524288
[8, 4]

33044255768277
[13, 9]
```

Comment: Can we return `[x, n]` instead of `[n, x]`?

Comment: Also, is there any time constraint?

Comment: `n` and `x` integers, right?

Comment: Output is in the form `[n, x]` and there is no time constraint @Fatalize

Comment: Yes, `n` and `x` are integers @LuisMendo

Comment: I have found 4 solutions for 2048 2048,1|32,2|2,8|1,2048 which of the 2 in the middle I should take? 524288,1|512,2|4,8|1,524288 has also 4 results

Comment: `[8, 2]` for 2048, as it's the pair of `n` and `x` with the smallest sum. Also `[8, 4]` for 524288. @JörgHülsermann

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 61 bytes

*Thanks to miles for saving 2 bytes, plus a whole bunch of bytes I counted for no reason!*

```
Last@Select[{n,(#/n)^(1/n)}~Table~{n,2Log@#},IntegerQ@*Last]&
```

Computes a table of pairs {n,x}, where x = (i/n)^(1/n), using all possible values of n; keeps only those for which the corresponding x is an integer; then returns the pair with the largest value of n.

Here, "all possible values of n" ranges from 1 to 2*ln(i). This ignores the solution {n,x} = {i,1}, but that's okay since the solution {n,x} = {1,i} will suffice if it's the best choice. So x never needs to get smaller than 2, which means that n*2^n ≤ i, and all such n are less than 2*ln(i).

One can show using calculus that the pair {n,x} that minimizes their sum in this context is the same as the pair {n,x} with largest n (not counting {i,1}). That's why the initial `Last` is good enough to find the optimal pair.

Comment: You can compose the test condition using `IntegerQ@*Last` to save 2 bytes, but I also count 63 not 86 bytes in this current version.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 35 bytes

```
,[N:X]#>>==L(.rMtT;Lr.rMtT),M^:T*?,
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=LFtOOlhdIz4-PT1MKC5yTXRUO0xyLnJNdFQpLE1eOlQqPyw&input=MzMwNDQyNTU3NjgyNzc&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

We construct a list `[N, X]`, where `N >= X`, then after assigning values to it, we  try both `[N, X]` and `[X, N]` as possible output. For example, if `N` gets assigned to `3`, we will test through backtracking `[3, 1]`, `[1, 3]`, `[3, 2]`, `[2, 3]`, `[3, 3]` and `[3, 3]`. After that the next backtracking step will occur on the value of `N`, which will go to `4`, etc.

```
,[N:X]     The list [N, X]
#>         Both N and X are strictly positive
>=         N >= X
=L         Assign values to N and X, and L = [N, X]
(          Either...
    .          Output = L
    rM         M is the reverse of the Output
    tT         T is the second element of M
;          ...or...
    Lr.        Output is the reverse of L
    rM         M = L
    tT         T is the last element of M
),
M^         First element of M to the power of the second element of L (T)...
:T*?,      ... times T is equal to the Input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 22 bytes

```
`T@XK:"@K@-@^*G=?3Mb~.
```

Outputs are `x`, `n` in that order.

Input is limited by MATL's default `double` data type, which can accurately represent integers up to `2^53` only. This excludes the first test (still, it gives the correct result, but that can't be guaranteed in general for inputs so large).

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YFRAWEs6IkBLQC1AXipHPT8zTWJ-Lg&input=MzMwNDQyNTU3NjgyNzc)

#### Explanation

The code uses two nested loops:

- The outer `do...while` loop goes through all possible sums `n+x` in increasing order. The loop will be stopped as soon as a solution is found. This guarantees that we output the solution with minimum sum.
- The inner `for each` loop tests all `n` and `x` with that sum. When the sum coincides with the input, the inner loop is exited and the loop condition of the outer loop is set to `false` so that one is exited too.

Commented code:

```
`         % Do...while
  T       %   Push "true". Will be used as loop condition (possibly negated to exit loop)
  @       %   Push iteration index, say K, which represents n+x
  XK      %   Copy that into clipboard K
  :       %   Range [1 2 ... K]
  "       %   For each
    @     %     Push loop variable (1, 2, ... K), which represents n
    K@-   %     Compute x as K minus n
    @     %     Push n again
    ^*    %     Power, multiply. This gives n*x^n
    G=    %     Does this equal the input?
    ?     %     If so
      3M  %       Push the inputs of the third-last function, that is, x and n
      b   %       Bubble up the "true" that is at the bottom of the stack
      ~   %       Transform it into "false". This will exit the do...while loop
      .   %       Break the for loop
          %     Implicitly end if
          %   Implicitly end for
          % Implicitly end do...while
          % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>23</s> 16 bytes

```
×*@¥/=³
ṗ2ÇÐfSÞḢ
```

Given `i`, this generates all integer pairs with replacement in `[1, i]`. It then performs the same filtering and sorting as in the previous solution shown below. Since there is no time constraint, brute force will work given enough time.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5cqQMKlLz3CswrhuZcyw4fDkGZTw57huKI&input=&args=MjQ), but don't try large values online.

On my pc, it takes about 6 minutes to compute the result for `i = 2048` using the inefficient version.

#### Efficient version

This is the previous solution for 23 bytes that is able to solve the large values quickly.

```
×*@¥/=³
ÆDµṚ*İ⁸żḞÇÐfSÞḢ
```

Given `i`, computes the divisors of `i` to generate pairs of `[n, x]` where `n` is a divisor and `x = floor( (i/n)^(1/n) )`. Then filters it for values where `n * x^n == i`, sort the remaining pairs by their sum, and returns the first pair.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5cqQMKlLz3CswrDhkTCteG5mirEsOKBuMW84biew4fDkGZTw57huKI&input=&args=MzMwNDQyNTU3NjgyNzc) or [Verify all test cases.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5cqQMKlLz3CrgrCucKpw4ZEwrXhuZoqxLDigbjFvOG4nsOHw5BmU8Oe4biiCsOH4oKs&input=&args=WzYyNjU4NzIyNTQxMjM0NzY1LCAyMDI1MDAsIDUyNDI4OCwgMzMwNDQyNTU3NjgyNzdd)

### Explanation

```
×*@¥/=³  Helper link. Input: list [n, x]
    /    Reduce using
   ¥       A dyadic chain
 *@        Compute x^n
×          Multiply by n
      ³  The initial value i
     =   Test if n * x^n == i

ṗ2ÇÐfSÞḢ  Main link (16 byte version). Input: integer i
ṗ2        Generate all pairs of integers in [1, i]
  ÇÐf     Filter for where the helper link is true
     SÞ   Sort them by their sum
       Ḣ  Return the first result

ÆDµṚ*İ⁸żḞÇÐfSÞḢ  Main link (23 byte version). Input: integer i
ÆD               Compute the divisors of i
  µ              Begin a new monadic chain operating on the divisors
   Ṛ             Reverse the divisors
     İ           Reciprocal of each divisors
    *            Raise each in the reversed divisors to the reciprocal of a divisor
      ⁸          Get the divisors
       ż         Interleave the divisors with the previous powers
        Ḟ        Floor each
         ÇÐf     Filter for where the helper link is true
            SÞ   Sort them by their sum
              Ḣ  Return the first result
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 104 Bytes

```
for(;1<$x=(($i=$argv[1])/++$n)**(1/$n);)!($x==ceil($x))?:$a[$x+$n]="[$x, $n]";ksort($a);echo$a[key($a)];
```

This outputs all possible solutions not in the proposed format 73 Bytes

```
for(;1<=$x=(($i=$argv[1])/++$n)**(1/$n);)!($x==ceil($x))?:print"$x,$n\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 52 bytes

Includes +2 for `-ap`

Give input on STDIN

```
mono.pl <<< 33044255768277
```

`mono.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ap
$_=("@F"/++$.)**(1/$.)while!/\./?$\="$. $_":$_>2}{
```

Took some effort to make it work for `1` too. I have no idea if floating point errors can make this return the wrong answer for some inputs.